# Mysql, python, SQL not executing

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Hi I have this basic mysql code:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO popularity (PersonNumber, Category, Value) VALUES (1,"Tennis","great")'
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost", user = "***",
passwd = "***", db = "inb104") 
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

However, this doesn't insert anything to the database. why? The sql syntax is correct, because I have coppied the outputted sql variable into the mysql console directly.  I know this code is working, because If I do: `sql =' SELECT * FROM popularity'` I can output the result in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
connection.commit()
```

that will do the trick =D

Answer (score 1):

You need to commit the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Because you forgot to commit the transaction before closing the cursor.